# How can I change the color of an SVG's child dynamically via props?

Tags: reactjs, svg

I'm importing the SVG with `ReactComponent`. Here is the related code:

```
import { ReactComponent as SuccessSVG } from "success.svg";

function SuccessIcon() {
  return <SuccessSVG />;
}
```

and this is the SVG itself:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 233.3 233.3">
  <circle class="circle" cx="116.65" cy="116.65" r="116.65" />
  <path
    class="ok"
    d="M97.28,167.38l-33.7-33.7a6.34,6.34,0,1,1,9-9l29.21,29.21,76-76a6.34,6.34,0,1,1,9,9l-80.48,80.48A6.34,6.34,0,0,1,97.28,167.38Z"
    transform="translate(-8.51 -6.01)"
  />
</svg>
```

I want to change `circle`'s and `path`'s colors dynamically via props. Something like this obviously:

```
function SuccessIcon({ circleColor, pathColor) {
  ...
  ...
}
```

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55367666/react-ability-to-control-fill-color-of-an-svg-through-props) already. I don't want to use the accepted answer's solution. The other answer is closer to my desire but I couldn't make it work.

By the way, I don't want to use the SVG directly in my component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already extracted `SuccessSVG` to its own component. Now you just need to pass via `props` the configurations you want to be dynamic

```
const SuccessSvg = ({ cx, cy }) => {
    return (
        <svg viewBox="0 0 233.3 233.3" >
            <circle class="circle" cx={cx} cy={cy} r="116.65" />
            <path
                class="ok"
                d="M97.28,167.38l-33.7-33.7a6.34,6.34,0,1,1,9-9l29.21,29.21,76-76a6.34,6.34,0,1,1,9,9l-80.48,80.48A6.34,6.34,0,0,1,97.28,167.38Z"
                transform="translate(-8.51 -6.01)"
            />
        </svg>
    )
}

const Component = () =>{
    return(
        <SuccessSvg color='blue' />
    )
}
```

Sadly you must consider the tradeoff. By declaring your `svg` as a stand alone component you write more code and have control over the customization. So that you can pass props which will be deeply applied inside your `jsx` structure

```
const CustomSVG = ({ svgProps, circleProps }) =>{
    return(
        <svg {...svgProps}>
            <circle {...circleProps} />
        </svg>
    )
}
```

This is why the OP for the linked question wraps the svg into a component, so that he can inject a custom `className` into the svg. Declarative components are awesome but you are limited by their API. In your case I don't see much alternatives, either abstract the structure to it's own component or use nested selectors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As stated in my last line "I don't want to use directly SVG in my component" actually I don't want to do that but I guess in this situation this is meaningless, right? Because if I do that then I don't need to import it as `ReactComponent`. I'm curious about that, isn't there any other way?

Comment: The `svg` must be implemented somewhere. It's a tradeoff, if you define your svg as a standalone component you'll be writing more code but have control over it's implementation. Case you're using a pre defined svg which doesn't suport customization then sadly you won't be able to change it. From where `success.svg` comes from? Is a react component?

Comment: No, directly from an SVG file. So, yes you are right about implementing it somewhere. I just wanted to keep the SVG files separately and define the related components importing them with `ReactComponent`. Using SVG attributes such as `fill`, `opacity`, etc for the `<svg>` itself is not a problem and it works as I intended but I couldn't find a way to style the child elements.

Comment: Instead of directly importing the `svg` couldn't you turn it into a function which accepts arbitrary arguments and returns the correspondent `jsx`?

Comment: Without `ReactComponent` you mean? I could do that I guess but since `ReactComponent` is so convenient for simple cases I wanted to try it like that. I thought maybe using `style` or anything else I can change the children's styles.

Comment: You don't want to change via `css selectors` right? `style` would only apply to `svg` itself.

Comment: Yes, I don't want to write every possible `css` variant in a `css` file :) My desire is very simple, for `circle` I'll pass a color, for `path` I'll pass a different color and it should work :) As I stated in my question the other question has a different answer but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: The other answer (not accepted) it's actually recommending that you declare your `svg` inside your component. I'm not sure if I'm understanding how you want to perform this customization. Could you write a pseudo code of how such customization should happen?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202155/discussion-between-devserkan-and-dupocas).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use a component as [@Dupocas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10106580/dupocas) suggested, **your only way** is to style your `SVG`:

```
// Example of CSS-in-JS , can be achieved with simple className.
const SVGContainer = styled.div`
  svg {
    path {
      fill: ${({ circleColor }) => circleColor};
    }
  }
`;

function SuccessIcon({ circleColor }) {
  return (
    <SVGContainer circleColor={circleColor}>
      <SuccessSVG />
    </SVGContainer>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  return <SuccessIcon circleColor="palevioletred" />;
};
```

[image: Edit react-antd-styled-template]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I do that without using `styled-components`? With pure CSS style? I'm using `css-modules` and `classnames` library but pure CSS is fine, too.

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement variables with pure css.

Comment: But that's a valid answer, you just need to figure out how you use variables with pure css

Comment: This is the reason for asking my question :) I couldn't find a way doing this with pure `CSS` or `React` way. Maybe I should have mentioned that I saw the `styled-components` alternative. I guess we can do this since it provides a wrapper component here and we can inject the `CSS` props. Nevertheless, thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

I still have not found a good solution for this problem. But I found this:

https://www.w3.org/TR/SVGParamPrimer/ : With this, we can write a webpack-loader, wrap the svg as data-url in an `object` element on it's `data` property, so we can pass props. And we can detect the props type from where it's used in the svg file. Of course, we need to write our svg in that syntax: `<rect fill="param(color) blue" stroke="param(outline) navy" />`

https://tabatkins.github.io/specs/svg-params/: This is't official, don't know will it be implemented.

Since solution one need to write the svg in that syntax, maybe it has no difference from copy svg code to jsx file and do some small changes.

I have another idea:

```
import SvgCar from './car.svg';
const vdom = <SvgCar>
  <replace
    // path="a relative path point to an element or a property"
    path="children[2].fill"
    to={'red'} />
</SvgCar>;

// or
const vdom2 = <SvgCar>{vdom => {vdom.children[2].fill="red";}}</SvgCar>
```

But I think this way will import so much coupling. It's not a good idea.